# Get current URL in PHP with DNS support

Tags: php, drupal, dns

For example, I have a PHP script located at `https://somesite.com/script.php`, but there's a DNS entry `sitewrapper.org` that points to `https://somesite.com/script.php`.  In this case, `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is `somesite.com`.  How can I access `sitewrapper.org`?

I need to execute some code based on the URL the user is accessing the site through, not the actual server name.

Comment: is `sitewrapper.org` a CNAME entry?

Comment: The DNS entry will not point to a link, but rather set sitewrapper.org as an alias to somesite.com. If the server is configured to handle both domains, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] should be properly set. If there is a redirect happening, the referer should be set in most cases. It would be helpful to see the DNS configuration of sitewrapper.org.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the details of the server configurations, I just know that my code doesn't work correctly on different environments.  I was hoping it was something I could work around the server configuration folks with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. It should contain host name and port, as it was requested by http client.

Comment: This ended up being the correct answer.  My confusion was how it different from SERVER_NAME, but it is giving me what I want - had to test on a non-local environment.  Thanks!